# java outofmemoryexception

Tags: java, memory, out-of-memory

```
There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
Native memory allocation (malloc) failed to allocate 180992 bytes for Chunk::new
Possible reasons:
  The system is out of physical RAM or swap space
  In 32 bit mode, the process size limit was hit
Possible solutions:
  Reduce memory load on the system
  Increase physical memory or swap space
  Check if swap backing store is full
  Use 64 bit Java on a 64 bit OS
  Decrease Java heap size (-Xmx/-Xms)
  Decrease number of Java threads
  Decrease Java thread stack sizes (-Xss)
  Set larger code cache with -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=
This output file may be truncated or incomplete.

Out of Memory Error (allocation.cpp:328), pid=71060, tid=71956
```

Im getting the above error when i run my game server on a small vps (only 1gb of ram)

Im not sure what could be the cause i have installed 64 bit java as its 64 bit

im using java -Xmx768m

Comment: I'd be skeptical you'd get away with allocating 3/4 of your physical memory to Java, but it depends on the system.

Comment: Im running windows 2008 not sure if thats important

Comment: I'm even more skeptical you'd get away with that on Windows 2008, since the operating system needs resources.  Try reducing `-Xmx`.

Answer (score 0):

Check your -Xms attribute also.

Comment: i havent set one what would you recomend

Comment: -Xms sets the minimum memory and won't help if you're running out of memory.